# IIS 8.5 application folder URL error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I have IIS 8.5 and under Sites > Default Web Site i have application folder Test. When i put my deployed application in that Test folder and enter localhost/Test in browser i am redirected to localhost/Test/Test and i get error. How can i prevent this extra /Test in my link to happen? Is that somewhere in IIS setting or is it application related (it's asp.net MVC 3/4 application).

When i put deployed application in Default Web Site root folder everything works fine but i need to have it in extra folder.

Comment: What's the full path of the deployed folder?

Comment: Default Web Site folder is C:\inetpub\wwwroot and Test folder is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test

Comment: And straight inside the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test folder you have your web.config and project files?

Comment: Did you just create a folder inside wwwroot or did you actually use the `Add Application...` option in IIS under the Default site?

Comment: I used Add Application in IIS and pointed to the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test where i have application files (publish from VS bin, content etc and web.config)

Comment: What is the default action in your app? Do you have a HomeController?

Comment: Home/Index is default action.